# ¿Como configurar el virtual host de apache?

Tags: linux, apache, apache2

Tengo configurado una ruta donde tengo unas imágenes esta ruta solo quiero que un host tenga permisos para leerlas pero al momento de hacer la peticion de la imagen me sale forbbiden

El imagen.conf de apache

```
    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin web@sitio.com
        ServerName imagenes.dev
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/imagenes

        <Directory /var/www/html/imagenes>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride All
            Require all granted
        </Directory>

        Alias /img /foot/Imagenes
       <Directory /foot/Imagenes>
          Require host "sitio.dev"
       </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

La peticion get de la imagen desde sitio.dev

```
Request URL: http://imagenes.dev/img/1606316683045
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 403 Forbidden
Remote Address: ip:443
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Referer: http://sitio.dev/
```